# Is there any way to catch Insert Event from MySQL Server

Tags: c++, mysql, sockets, events, named-pipes

I wonder if there are any way to catch events (like OnRowInsert, OnRowUdate,  OnRowDelete) from MySQL in a third-party windows app?

I did not find any way but raise such event with UDP (user defined function) using sockets or named pipe.

Right now my solution is next:

1. Listener open named pipe and wait for connections and data from
   MySQL;
2. In MySQL create trigger on Insert/Update/Delete on table I
   need;
3. Call UDP function PipeNotification(TableName, Operation) in
   trigger;
4. In PipeNotification connect to listener's named pipe and write data.

btw: you can ask my solution [here](http://shadowofaero.blogspot.com)

So, maybe I had not to invent a bicycle?